# Shifting the nonzero homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Suppose there is a finite chain complex
$$C_{n} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow C_{d}\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow C_{0}\,,$$
such that $H_{i}(C_{\bullet})$ is vanished except for $i=d$.

Are there any general processes of modifying the complex (still index from $n$ to $0$) so that the homology is unvanished only in $d-1$ or $d+1$-th place and the nonzero homology is same as $H_{d}(C_{\bullet})$? The ultimate goal is shifting the nonzero homology to the head or tail.

Many thanks.

Comment: I mean you could reindex. What exactly do you mean by modifying the complex?